# looping on a count in jsRender not working

Tags: jsrender

I have the following:

```
 {{for Basket.Items itemVar="~product"}}
    {{for ~product.Qty}}
       ......
    {{/for}}
  {{/for}}
```

where ~product.Qty = 2. it only goes through the loop once. how do I make the inner for loop for the amount of times that Qty equals?

So I might have 3 basket items and 1 of those items I might have a qty of 2, so I want my template to display the item with qty of 2 twice

Answer (score 0):

To [interate over a range of numbers](https://www.jsviews.com/#fortag@number-range), you need to put `~product.Qty` not as an argument to `{{for}}` as in `{{for ~product.Qty}}`, but as named `end` property: `{{for end=~product.Qty}}`.

For example:

```
{{for Basket.Items itemVar="~product"}}
  {{for end=Qty||1}}
     <div>{{:#index}} {{:~product.Name}}</div>
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

or

```
{{for Basket.Items itemVar="~product"}}
  {{for end=~product.Qty||1 itemVar="~item"}}
     <div>{{: ~item}} {{: ~product.Name}}</div>
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

with:

```
data = {Basket: { 
    Items: [
        {Name: "A", Qty: 2},
        {Name: "B", Qty: 3},
        {Name: "C"},
        {Name: "D", Qty: 1}
    ]
}};
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. From your data example I want to see Name "A" twice on screen because QTY is 2, Name "B" 3 times, "C" once and "D" once. I still only see my item once.

Comment: If I use your first example, at the end of the inner for if I do `{{:#index}}` it looks as though it has looped for the qty amount, but I only see 1 item i.e. Name "A" once as opposed to twice, but I get on screen for both `For #index in nested block use #getIndex()`

Comment: @bilpor everything works as you want - [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5aoqgxjt/)

Comment: I hit the run button in jsFiddle nothing happens

Comment: Hit the "render template" button!! It works perfectly. Thanks Codd Wrench.